# Error while building vuforia sample project

Tags: android, vuforia

I have tried to build `vuforia` sample project. But while running the project, it is showing an alert with *"Your project containing problem please fix the error".*

And in console showing following error:

> Buildfile: /home/krish/AndroidStudioProjects/Vuforia-Pro/CopyVuforiaFiles.xml
>   CopyVuforiaSo:
>               [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/krish/AndroidStudioProjects/Vuforia-Pro/libs/armeabi-v7a
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>   Total time: 318 milliseconds

In this xml file only error showing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="VuforiaSamples" default="CopyVuforiaSo">
<target name="CopyVuforiaSo">
    <copy overwrite="true" todir="libs/armeabi-v7a">
        <fileset dir="../../build/lib/armeabi-v7a"/>
    </copy>
</target>
```

And Red colour Exclamatory  Symbol showing near of project folder in eclipse.

I am using ubuntu os. Please tell what is the problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found that error. In vuforia they changed class name from ImageTraker into ObjectTraker. So we need to change the class name manually.